# Rails AJAX insert partial into div

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a lot of data in a model that needs many forms to edit.  What I've done is create a page that takes options like ?id=something&otheroption=something else and renders the correct edit form based on those inputs.  Now, I am trying to create the actual edit page.  The plan is for the user to select the "id" and "otheroption" from a drop down, and then an AJAX call will update a DIV with the correct form.

What I need to to is put this into a partial in someway where I can send an AJAX request to, have rails process the options, render the partial, and return the AJAX request.  How do I do that with JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is create a controller action with a js response that then renders a partial. As an example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="div_id"></div>
```

**Controller**

```
def ajax_responder

  @data = query

  respond_to do |format|
   format.js
  end
end
```

**JS partial**

```
jQuery("#div_id").html("<%= escape_javascript(render "html_partial")  %>");
```

**HTML Partial**

```
whatever your html partial with data would be
```

This may suck mightily... I am open to feedback.

Comment: I don't understand where it is rendering the partial.  Why wouldn't the controller code simply return @data as the response?

Comment: It's also giving me this error: Missing partial dashboard/_get_form, application/_get_form with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * /app/views", but the partial _get_form is at /app/views/dashboard/_get_form.html.rb